# CISCO VPN CLIENT + on linux machines

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco

I have try to install the VPNC Cisco client on many linux red-hat version

For example

```
 Linux 5.2 ( red-hat )
 Linux 6.2 ( red-hat )
 Linux 6.3 ( red-hat )
```

And on different kind of kernel versions

Until now some installation was failed during ./vpn_install ( compilation problem )

And some after installation was succeeded , BUT  I have problems with connection ( with many kind of problems )

```
 vpnclient connect .....
```

Please advice what the right VPN CISCO version that need to install on the right linux version ( kernel ) , and maybe we need to prefer linux with 32 bit ?

I work on this more then week but without any success please help

Comment: Have you talked with your Cisco support rep about this? Perhaps try [vpnc](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/vpnc) instead of the official Cisco client.

Comment: how to download the VPNC on my red-hat machine ? from which site?

Comment: is it possible to install it on linux red-hat I maybe I need to downlaod the OS CentOS?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to install in RHEL. That said, we don't do how-to guides here. Do a bit of research and figure it out on your own.